# Titlecase all entries into a form_for text field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

Trying to title-case all the entries from a form_for field so they're consistent going into the database for searches.

Here is my search field (file created as a partial):

```
<%= form_for @airport do |f| %>  
Input city  
<%= f.text_field :city, :value => f.object.city.titlecase %>  
Input country  
<%= f.text_field :country, :value => f.object.country.titlecase %>  
<%= f.submit %>  
<% end %>
```

But when I run it I get a NoMethodError:

`undefined method 'titlecase' for nil:NilClass`

I took instruction on the `.object.city.titlecase` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951202/capitalize-f-text-field).

Can anyone help?

Comment: The error message comes from the fact that the value of `f.object.city` or `f.object.city` is `nil`. And `nil` doesn't have a `titlecase` method, so there's an error.

Comment: Since it's an empty form, won't the value always be nil tho? How would you write it so anything entered into the form is titlecased, then?

Comment: See my answer below for what you want to do server-side. You could use Javascript to capitalize things as the user types them, but that might be confusing to the user.

Comment: Later Ruby versions, allow you to simulate a useable web-scripting-language by using this: "f.object.city&.titlecase"  - the "&" says, essentially, "Of course, just return nil and don't crash the page if a property of nil is requested."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to take care of normalizing your data in a view - what if the user changes the data that gets submitted? Instead you could take care of it in the model using the `before_save` (or the `before_validation`) callback. Here's an example of the relevant code for a model like yours:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save do |place|
    place.city = place.city.downcase.titleize
    place.country = place.country.downcase.titleize
  end
end
```

You can also check out [the Ruby on Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) for more info.

---

To answer you question more directly, something like this would work:

```
<%= f.text_field :city, :value => (f.object.city ? f.object.city.titlecase : '') %>
```

This just means if `f.object.city` exists, display the `titlecase` version of it, and if it doesn't display a blank string.